# Cleaner way to check if number is in array C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to check if a number is in an array in C++.
The solution I have is kinda messy:

```
int luckynumbers[5] = { 3, 5, 8, 15, 19};

std::cout << "Enter number from 1 - 20: ";
int choice;

std::cin >> choice;
if (choice == luckynumbers[0] || luckynumbers[1] || luckynumbers[2] || luckynumbers[3] || luckynumbers[4])
{
    std::cout << "You are lucky!";
}
```

Anyone has any tips/better practice ways to write the `if` statement part?

Comment: That `if` statement doesn't even do what you think it does. You'll be surprised to learn that it doesn't actually check if `choice` is in the array. So, yes, there are better ways to write that. Any way that actually does it correctly would be better, of course.

Comment: If your container is over 1mb in size, you may want to consider using `std::binary_search`, otherwise, use a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop

```
int luckynumbers[5] = { 3, 5, 8, 15, 19};

std::cout << "Enter number from 1 - 20: ";
int choice;

std::cin >> choice;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // or whatever the size of your array is
   if(choice == luckynumbers[i]) {
          std::cout << "You are lucky!";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try using loops.

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
if(luckynumber[i]==choice){
   cout<<"You're Lucky"<<endl;
}
}
```